# having char[1] and offset how to read int?

Tags: c++

I have such structure

```
typedef struct {
int32_t  DataLen;
char     Data[1];
} MTEMSG;
```

So `Data` contains `DataLen` symbols that should be decoded by certain rules. I should write `ReadInt` `ReadString` etc methods.

As a first step I want to write `ReadInt`. From documentation this is "Four bytes in a format of x86 CPU (the little-endian byte goes first)." How can I convert `char[1]` to `int`? I guess it should be something like:

```
MTEMSG* data;
int offset;
....
int Reader::ReadInt()
{
int result = // read 4 bytes starting from offset
offset += 4;
}
```

It's allowed to use `boost` and `c++11`. Just looking for simple and fast method to convert.

I hope once you suggest me how to convert `int` I can do many of the rest methods myself.

Comment: That’s illegal C++. You’re not allowed to read past the length of the array, even if you have allocated more space for it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph i can not change API, so i have nothing than rely on it.

Comment: @Konrad, so some Windows structures ([BITMAPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375.aspx) comes to mind) are invalid C++?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes.

Comment: Thanks guys, you learn something new every day :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi but this legal kind of C or C++ UB-addicts speaking about is totally useless. So anyway we have to use some hypothetically 'illegal' constructions to improve interfaces, performance, etc.

Comment: @keltar You’re wrong. These cases of UB (= writing to pointers outside of static array bounds) actual cause real, observable problems because they violate the optimiser’s assumptions, and this in turn produces buggy code in some instances. Now since the WinAPI uses such code we can be sure that the Microsoft C++ compiler will know not to meddle with this particular example. Other compilers, however, may do different things.

Comment: @keltar, it's not useless. UB has two very likely side effects: 1. the optimizer may break your code, 2. your code won't be portable. If you however stick to a single compiler (for example microsoft's) **for which the behavior is actually well-defined**, then there's no problem with using constructs illegal by the standard.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it's far from being only microsoft. Actually seen this pattern so many times i've stopped counting. Plus, cast pointer to different structure probably illegal too - still very widely used. I strongly believe this approach will cause problems on some very exotic platforms - but again, even platforms with non-8bit bytes exists, but who would ever port existing software to this architectures?

Comment: @Shahbaz sure. And (void*)0 is not necessary to be all-0 bits (at least standard don't require that). Still not worth avoiding memset(0) - for both ease-of-read and performance reasons.

Comment: @keltar, "very widely used" is actually sad. There are much more portable ways to convert data from a struct to an array and vice-versa. People who do that probably only code for x86. If you have ever coded for arm (includes smartphones), pic, or various other microcontrollers, you would immediately realize that "thee lines of standard code" is _much_ better than a "one line x86 hack"

Comment: It looks undefined behaviour, but as long as the filling/reading is done on same compiler/process, that allocation is well made and struct copy is controled. I'm pretty sure it would work on almost everything. The only pitfall could be optimiser (can't be sure it will do something or nothing, but it could be disabled on that code if pb occurs) or static analyser which will spot that very fast every time.

Comment: @keltar, besides, C++ has constructors which can be used for initialization and C has designated initializers. Instead of `memset` you can easily do (in C) `for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) array[i] = (type){0};` which correctly sets even `NULL` to the correct pattern. In C++ you have probably already used `std::vector` anyway

Comment: @keltar It’s widely used but that doesn’t mean it cannot cause problems. It *does* cause problems. I cannot find a link now but there was at least one bug caused by that in a big OSS project. As for the cast from `char` to another type, no, that’s *not* illegal, it’s totally fine. Little-endianness is of course implementation-defined but again, it’s perfectly legal.

Comment: @Shahbaz i meant structures that contains pointers (worse - probably within substructures). And C89 don't have this feature anyway. And yes, i do code for arm and mips in addition to x86/amd64. If you avoiding hardware details in favor of portability - well, it's obvious that performance will fall, is it still reasonable to stick with C then? This is what i initially meant. I don't want to offend all who speaks of UB - it just don't making sense to me using C without going deep to hardware.

Comment: coldcat, If you have ever seen/written code that works in debug but not in release, there's your UB. ;)

Comment: @KonradRudolph MS compiler, gcc and clang have unsized (or zero-sized) arrays feature for exactly this case. How on earth this could fail, if they specifically designed to handle this situation, and even added their own extension to language? On some unknown compilers - well, i assume programmer knows what he is doing.

Comment: @keltar Unsized/zero-sized is different from size=1. They are special cases for which exceptions are hard-coded into the compiler so that the optimiser knows about them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html gcc doc suggests [1] if gcc-extension is for some reason unavailable. I get it as gcc obligated to correctly handle this case for [1], and almost sure microsoft doc will tell something very like this.

Answer (score 2):

Totally illegal and UB, but you would do something like `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(data+offset)`.

Watch out for alignment and stuff.

Comment: or just `*(data->Data + offset)` ?

Comment: @javapowered That would give you a `char`, not an `int`.

Comment: @javapowered `*(int*)(data->Data+offset)` if you want C-style syntax

Comment: @Shahbaz That makes no sense whatsoever. The code *is* illegal, pointing this out is necessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I was talking about the expression. `data+offset` has problems with "alignment and stuff" as said (at least, it should have been `data->Data+offset`). Second, casting it to `int *` like that assumes the running architecture is also little-endian and that `int` also has 32-bits. The code in question is UB by the standard, but not by microsoft's compiler. This answer to the question is really UB.

Comment: @Shahbaz We’re already making assumptions about the compiler anyway. Doesn’t the Microsoft compiler guarantee the underlying architecture (little endian) as well? I’ve seen plenty of WinAPI code which assumes that (but that was admittedly before mobile & Xbox). Furthermore, even if that is not the case, this behaviour is *not* UB, merely implementation-defined. That’s a whole different thing, and the distinction is quite important.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, actually I don't know. I don't do microsoft C++. Anyway, about your previous comment, I think the _"Totally illegal and UB,"_ wasn't referring to the code of the OP, but to the following sentence. For example, if you say _"It may not work, but you could also try X"_ or _"Quite useless, but I love the `-->` operator"_ the part before `,` refers to what comes after. Nevertheless, like I said it should have _at least_ been `data->Data + offset` even with all those assumptions. That way at least you aren't concerned with alignments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in C++ as they have stated in the comments, this is illegal. Nevertheless, assuming your compiler assumes you might do something like this and has a well-defined behavior for it, then let's go ahead.

So *semantically*, you have such a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t  DataLen;
    char     Data[N];
} MTEMSG;
```

where `N` is "large enough".

And you need to convert `Data` to a 4-byte little endian integer. That's quite simple:

```
MTEMSG* data;
int offset = 0;
....
int Reader::ReadInt()
{
    /* Note: int32_t would be more precise */
    int result = data->Data[offset + 0]
              | (data->Data[offset + 1] << 8)
              | (data->Data[offset + 2] << 16)
              | (data->Data[offset + 3] << 24);
    offset += 4;
}
```

Comment: why not just cast to `int` as suggested in another answer?

Comment: @javapowered, see my comment on the other answer. The way my answer is written has well-defined semantics. Casting the contents of a `char` array to `int` assumes many things about the compiler and the architecture which can simply not be true.

Comment: so yours version does work on all platforms, but much slower than another version that works on certain platforms only?

Comment: @javapowered, if `0.00000001%` is much slower to you, then yes. I assume you are doing something with the resulting integer, so you don't spend all your time just converting integers. Also note that since the data are contiguous, they are most likely all loaded in cache at the same time and your "certain platform" (aka x86) has already parallelized the shifts and ors. If you are really concerned about performance, you can always plug the two code in your program and measure the time. If even a millisecond of difference was registered, then by all means use the hack.

Comment: So assuming little-endian is better than converting to different type? Sorry but this is too odd for me.

Comment: @keltar: the op says: `From documentation this is "Four bytes in a format of x86 CPU (the little-endian byte goes first)."`. So the input is stored little-endian. Also, bit shifting takes care of the endianness, so `<<` always shifts to more significant bits be it little endian or big endian

Comment: Erm wait... The original discussion under question started with words 'you can't read past array size'. But you just did it via offset, didn't you? So, how is it better/more portable/etc.?

Comment: @keltar, listen, I was also annoyed when I got to SO and everyone was talking about UB. At that time, like you, I didn't see the point of it and was thinking "why so strict". In fact, see [this question of mine](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/107601/36503) about the exact same thing. But over time I came to realize UB is the root of most of the problems I've ever had or have seen others have.

Comment: @Shahbaz sure. Still don't see how three-lines of only-little-endian code better than one line of still only-little-endian code.

Comment: @keltar, my code is not little-endian only. The contents of the array are little-endian as stated in the documentation of the source it came from. The `int result` that is calculated in this code has the value of that integer regardless of whether the architecture running this code is little-endian or big-endian. This is a feature of C and C++ that have well-defined semantics for shift left which takes care of endianness.

Comment: Think of two computers that exchange data in messages through the network. They need to define the structure of the data they pass around, for example saying it's always little-endian. The other computer that converts the data back should read little-endian, but store as whatever endianness it has.

Comment: @Shahbaz my false assumptions, sorry. Thanks for clarifying shifts for big-endian, this behaviour seemed too illogic to be true.

Comment: @keltar, It seems illogical at first, that's true. But the C standard (which C++ followed) decided it can't possibly make shifts portable unless it is defined this way. In fact, the C (and C++) standards assume a hypothetical machine (called _abstract machine_) over which the operations are defined. It's the job of the compiler to make the processor act like the abstract machine.